# Is the question ""Does it exist what I'm looking for?" " the most usual way to ask a question in this meaning?

Tags: american-english, questions, phrase-usage

I'm doing a translation from Portuguese to English, and I've found a phrase that is a simple question, but I don't know if it exists, because it simply doesn't exist on Google, with one exception.

"Does it exist what I'm looking for?" in Google just returns [1 hit](https://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/relationships/4447655-Thought-I-would-be-happy-by-now-wtf).

All main free translators (Google Translate, Bing Translate and ChatGPT) pretend that undertand this wrong question.

Right questions in English

1. "Does it exist?"
2. "What am I looking for?"
3. "Did he do his homework?"
4. "Did he do it?"

It seems to me that somehow putting together the construction "Did/do/does" + preposition + Verb" is OK, but when one adds "What" + preposition + "verb" sometimes is right (e.g. "Did you do what I asked you yesterday?") sometimes becomes wrong("Does it exist what I'm looking for").

Can someone who speaks English as a native language tell me if this construction is correct or if there is an alternative way of asking the question in this sense? What would be the preferable mode then?

Comment: It'll be two hits by now :)

Comment: What is wrong with the more normal English construction "Does what I am looking for exist?"

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: The _it_ subject is not necessary; third person singular on _exist_ or _does_ is enough.  But you can't start a question with *_Does exist_ -- that has to be split up by the subject clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler Because fused relative constructions are NPs they don’t appear in extraposition constructions, I don’t think.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. No, they can't. Extraposed clauses can be infinitives, gerunds, _that_-complements,  or embedded question  complements. But not fused relatives. Of course all those other complements are NPs too, so that's probly not the simple reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That construction isn't grammatical. If I understand the meaning right, you could phrase it

- "Does what I'm looking for exist?", or
- "Does the thing I'm looking for exist?"

Comment: Clearly you are right. There are 70 hits on Google.

Comment: But why isn’t it grammatical? “Does it matter what I’m looking for?” Is fine.

Comment: I don't know, @Araucaria-Nothereanymore, but also it not occurs in Google Search.

Comment: @PauloBuchsbaum It’s because “what I’m looking for” in my example is an interrogative clause. But in your example, it is a noun phrase. It means “the thing which I am looking for”. Noun phrases don’t occur in extraposition constructions (where you put the word  “it” in subject position and move the clause to the end of the sentence).

Comment: Here's a plainer explanation. The verb "to exist" is intransitive ("I exist"), so the question word "what" can only go where the subject should go ("what exists?", not "it exists what?"). Just as "who speaks?" is correct but "it speaks who?" is not. It's true that a construction of the form "it <verb> what/who/where" exists in the case of "it matters", "it's irrelevant", "I don't care" etc., and why that works could be an interesting question to ask on its own.

Comment: @Glaucon No, because the *what* in OP’s example is not an interrogative word. *Matter* is an intransitive verb but “Does it matter what I’m looking for?* is fine, and **does** use interrogative *what*!

Comment: I'm not sure the *what* in OP's example is anything at all, because the sentence doesn't parse. Are you saying that your construction with *matter* tells us something about a general rule that applies to all intransitive verbs? What is the rule?

Comment: No, transitivity has nothing to do with anything here. The OP's example is an attempt to use a free-relative (fused relative construction) in an extraposition construction. This is ungrammatical in English.

Comment: I understand your analysis, but I'm not convinced it's the source of OP's mistake. Can we be sure OP wasn't just confused about the correct word order of 'what' questions? Or that he wasn't reasoning by analogy with another language in which '*it exists' is interchangeable with 'there is'?